# Cygwin fatal error unable to remap.. What does it mean?

Tags: windows-7, bash, cygwin

When running `python` in cygwin, I get the following error:

```
    0 [main] python 6140 C:\cygwin\bin\python.exe: *** fatal error - unable to remap \\?\C:\cygwin\lib\python2.6\lib-dynload\time.dll to same address as parent: 0x2B0000 != 0x360000
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
00288E68  6102749B  (00288E68, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000)
00289158  6102749B  (61177B80, 00008000, 00000000, 61179977)
0028A188  61004AFB  (611A136C, 6124112C, 002B0000, 00360000)
End of stack trace
    0 [main] python 9048 fork: child 6140 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
abort: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

What does it mean, and what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to run the `rebaseall` command from the `rebase` package to fix the problem.

1. Install the `rebase` package using the Cygwin `setup.exe` utility
2. Close everything running that uses the `cygwin1.dll`
3. Open a Cygwin shell
4. Type `rebaseall` at the prompt

Rebasing is usually only required when installed packages are installed that modify libraries that are dynamically loaded. I'll admit a bad habit of always running `rebaseall` after installing or upgrading packages in a Cygwin install rather than waiting for that error you hit to show up.

As for why you got that error and how rebasing solves the problem, [this post](http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2009-05/msg00413.html) has this to say about it:

> You have it backwards.  Forking doesn't break the relocation.  Relocation
>   breaks forking.  cygwin1.dll needs to have a very special memory layout to
>   implement the fork semantics in Win32.  If this memory layout is disrupted,
>   fork breaks.  Relocating cygwin1.dll disrupts the required memory layout.
>   'rebaseall' does its best to locate all Cygwin DLLs that it knows of
>   into a layout that avoids collisions.  This maintains the required
>   memory layout so fork can do its job.

Comment: i was trying this and it didn't work... that is until i restarted windows (after a rebaseall and peflagsall)

Comment: Ian C: You are my hero!

Comment: Also, rebaseall seems to need Administrator rights on Windows 7.

Comment: Sepcifying a base address could in some cases help, as suggested here: http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2011-04/msg00306.html

Comment: You need to do this in ash or dash not through the normal Cygwin Terminal. Launch it with Start -> Run, its in cygwin\usr\bin\ash. Once ash is running, type /usr/bin/rebaseall and hit enter.

Comment: I am trying to rebase but bin/ash, bin/ash, bin/dash, and bin/rebase won't start. Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: I meant bin/bash, bin/ash, bin/dash, and bin/rebase won't start.

Comment: @Giorgio you should ask a new question.

Comment: @Ian C: I did not want to add a new question if it is not needed. I will try to figure out what went wrong and in case I don't find what the problem is I will ask a new question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 11):

It means that either a 3rd party program such as a virus scanner or the DLL address randomisation feature that was introduced in Vista have interfered with your process in such a way that it couldn't successfully be forked.

The `rebaseall` utility can be used to pin down DLLs such that the problem is avoided. It's installed by default. See `rebaseall --help` on how to use it, and `/usr/share/doc/Cygwin/rebase-3.0.1.README` for further details. If it doesn't help, `peflagsall` is another one worth trying.

Comment: thanks =) both answers helped me out... but i can only accept one =\

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem after compiling "numpy". Die affected dll was mtrand.dll. Simple

```
$ /bin/rebaseall
```

did not work.

What helped was the following:
Examine whether the affected dll (in this case time.dll) is acutally "rebased":

```
$ /bin/rebaseall -v
```

If not create a list which contains the full path of the affected dll. E.g.:

```
$ find /lib -name 'time.dll' > /tmp/mydll.txt
```

The file may also contain more dlls, one per line.
Then, call

```
$ /bin/rebaseall -v -T /tmp/mydll.txt
```

with no other cygwin stuff running, as described above.
The time.dll should now be rebased (additionally to the "normal" rebaseall).

(Strange: In 10 years of using cygwin with nt, windows2000, xp, I had to "rebase" only once. In one day with (64 bit) window-7 this was already neccessary.)

Answer (score 2):

There is answer for the problem.

Source: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Building-node.js-on-Cygwin-(Windows)

---

### Unable to Remap to Same Address as Parent

> `fatal error – unable to remap \?\C:\cygwin\lib\python2.6\lib-dynload\time.dll to same address as parent: 0×360000 != 0×3E0000`

This is not an issue with node.js either. Install base → rebase using setup.exe first then close all Cygwin instances. Start dash or ash (located in the bin directory under Cygwin's installation) and run:

> `$ /bin/rebaseall -v`

It should finish with no errors. If instead the above results in an error like:

> `rebaseall:'/cygdrive/c/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp' is not writable`

Open up a Cygwin shell and run:

> `$ chmod 777 ~/AppData/Local/Temp`

Close your shell window and repeat the steps above.
Once you are done, restart your PC. Remember to close all open Cygwin shells before using rebaseall.

Comment: It's good practice to copy the information from the link for future users in case the link ever fails.