# Trouble using Cygwin rebaseall: "only ash or dash processes

Tags: command-line, cygwin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running rebaseall on Cygwin](https://superuser.com/questions/231590/running-rebaseall-on-cygwin)

I'm following the instructions from this post on how to run the rebaseall command:
[Cygwin fatal error unable to remap.. What does it mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/194529/cygwin-fatal-error-unable-to-remap-what-does-it-mean)

After I enter "rebaseall" (in Cygwin bash), I get the following message:

> rebaseall: only ash or dash processes are allowed during rebasing. 
>   Exit all Cygwin processes and stop all Cygwin services. 
>   Execute ash  from Start/Run... or a cmd or command window. Execute '/bin/rebaseall' from ash

I also tried the same (after restarting computer) in the Windows command prompt and get the same exact result.

How can I rebaseall?

Comment: see also  http://superuser.com/questions/231590/running-rebaseall-on-cygwin which gives fuller answer to same question.

Answer (score 2):

Run ash.exe from the cygwin bin directory from Windows explorer or the Start->run on the desktop.
From the ash prompt run rebaseall.