# Can I mount a (zip) archive in cygwin?

Tags: mount, cygwin, zip, fstab

I do not see any example in http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#mount-table =

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just unzip the archive?

Comment: Indeed, is there any reason to use the mount at all if we can simply extract our resource into file system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[fuse-zip](https://code.google.com/p/fuse-zip/) is a project that enables mounting .zip archives via [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) ([Wikipedia entry of FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace), might be a better first introduction).

[This mailing list thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bup-list/Y9zXCdNwEoM) and [this SO question](https://superuser.com/q/194529/49184) has some pointers in getting FUSE running on Cygwin, it seems.

But no, I would not assume it to be native functionality in Cygwin. If you just want to browse the archive and extract single files, there are easier ways via any normal archive handler program, though.